# cypress.visit is redirecting to the same domain with the suffix __/

Tags: automation, e2e-testing, cypress, end-to-end

I have a problem using Cypress when running tests on our staging domain. For some reason Cypres browser opens the correct website but then immediately changes the url to the absolute domain and appends `__/` at the end:

`https://stagingdomain.com/administrators/login` becomes `https://stagingdomain.com/__/`

On production this does not happen, the test passes correctly. Sidenote: Our staging environment is only accessible behind our corporate VPN, but besides that everything else is the same

```
  it('Gets, types and asserts', function () {
    cy.visit('https://stagingdomain.com/administrators/login');

    cy.contains('ADMIN LOGIN'); 

    cy.url().should('include', 'administrators');
  });

});
```

I have followed all security measures provided on Cypress' documentation but none seem to be resolving this issue. Wondering if anyone else has faced the same challenge and has been able to overcome it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a known issue with Cypress which was since addressed in version 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

This is still any issue in 5.1.0.

I clearly have a page redirect to `index.php` which is in `http://url.com/site/`
Instead of redirecting to `http://url.com/site/index.php` like it should. The page is redirected to `http://url.com/__/index.php` which does not exist. It seems to be an issue with the doc root rewrite.

I also tried adding these to my `cypress.json` with no luck:

```json
{
  "baseUrl": "http://url.com/site/index.php",
  "experimentalSourceRewriting": true
}
```

As a workaround, I simply redirect the user again and they check if the session is valid by getting to my secure page after my login.